# Mod Rewrite causes internal server error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just used this code from a mod rewrite generator, but if I try to click on a link that refers to products.php it causes in an internal server errror:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?content=$1 [L]
```

Please help, I don't even have a clue what to do here.

Edit:
I have another last question. Urls now look like this:

http://www.exampledomain.com/examplecat/

but I want to append parameters like this

http://www.exampledomain.com/examplecat/?id=5&sortcol=model&sortdirection=asc

At the moment it seems like my Rewrite Rule above doesn't append it at all.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" could be almost anything.  This is an intentionally opaque error message shown to the user in the browser.  You have to look at your server logs to see what is really going on.

Comment: when i change the rule to RewriteRule ^products.php$ /index.php?content=products [L] it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have been

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrited
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?content=$1&rewrited=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It worked now with your solution. But I had to move the htaccess to my www folder first, not root